# How to pass parameter to the Jasper IReport

Tags: java, sqlite, jasper-reports

Hello all i wanna ask something i have design a form where it is connected using `sqlite`. Everything was going smoothly and suddenly I am out of ideas. Below is basically a form that i have design. What i want is when user press the compile button it will and ask the user to select a picture and with all the records that the user fill in the form including together with all the text in the `JLabel`, `JCheckbox`  to be attach below of the picture is like a watermark. I try to create this in `Jasper IReport` and i have manage to get only the data that is in database which user have selected. Please if u guys can help me i would be much appreciated

As you can see only the `JCombobox` and `JLabel` is linked to the database. My system function will work when the customer select from the combobox then it will show an image in the `JLabel`. This is my coding for image:

#### In my SQlite there is a table name KKKB1 and collumn name "Sains" and "Pangkat"

`Pangkat` = ComboBox1 (JComboBox)

`Sains` = Image(JLabel

### Declaration

`private ImageIcon format = null;`

### Code to change from blob to imageicon

I have change my jlabel variable to "image"

`byte[] imagedata = rs.getBytes("Sains");
         format = new ImageIcon(imagedata);
         image.setIcon(format);`

### Below is my code for combobox

```
private void Fillcombo(){

    try{
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM KKKB1";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
        String name = rs.getString("Pangkat");
        ComboBox1.addItem(name);
        ComboBox1.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }
}

  private void ComboBox1PopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent evt) {                                                       

    try{
     String sql= "SELECT * FROM KKKB1 WHERE Pangkat = '"+ComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"'";   
     pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     rs=pst.executeQuery();
     if (rs.next()){
     byte[] imagedata = rs.getBytes("Sains");
     format = new ImageIcon(imagedata);
     image.setIcon(format);
     }

    }
    catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
} `
```

This is where the problem comes in, when i press the compile button i want show a file chooser where user will select their picture and get all the data from the form including the text in the texfield and checkbox where user have key in and to display in Jasper Ireport together with the picture that user have select. I have manage to do until this part please help me to achieve my objective

### Below is my code for Jasper Ireport

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try{

    JasperDesign jd =JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\Users\\AsySyah\\Desktop\\KKKBProject\\KKKBProject\\KKKBReport.jrxml");
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM KKKB1 WHERE Pangkat = '"+ComboBox1.getSelectedItem()+"'";

    JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
    newQuery.setText(sql);
    jd.setQuery(newQuery);
    JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
    JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null, conn);
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);

    }
    catch(Exception e){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

Im very sorry if cant post any image of my interface and output because of my low reputation and new. If i can do that i will be much clearer for u guys to see :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the form input data in a report you should either:

- save it in the database,
- or send them as report parameters.

The general idea is something like this:

```
..
JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);

// Put values from all form controls into a parameter map.
Map<String, Object> formValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
formValues.put("FORM_COMBO", ComboBox1.getSelectedItem().getText());
formValues.put("FORM_TEXT", someJTextField.getText());
..

// Give the parameters to the report filler.
JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, formValues, conn);
```

In the report itself you can access report parameters with `$P{FORM_COMBO}` (I think).
You can send the image the same way, i.e. as one of the parameters.

More details in [this article](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_report_parameters.htm).